# Standard of communications between dapps and dapp browsers

Tags: eosjs, scatter, meet.one-wallet, lynx-wallet

I am building a dapp on EOS, and wondered what is the best practice of communicating with the dapp browser.

For example on Ethereum I implemented the web3 library and all commands and apis were through it, by that, I wrote the code once, and it automatically triggered the relevant UI screens on the dapp browser.

Is there something similar with EOS? I don't want to write specific code for each dapp browser (Scatter, lynx, meet one etc..)

Answer (score 2):

Block.one released the ***Universal Authenticator Library - UAL*** a week ago.

Here are some helpful links:

- [Medium Article about the UAL](https://medium.com/eosio/eosio-labs-release-the-universal-authenticator-library-ual-increasing-the-accessibility-of-8e2bd62a78a5)
- [UAL Authenticator Walkthrough](https://github.com/EOSIO/ual-authenticator-walkthrough)
- [UAL Github-Repository](https://github.com/EOSIO/universal-authenticator-library)

There are are several different UAL-Repositories + Usage-Examples for use with the different available Wallets.

- [Scattter UAL](https://github.com/EOSIO/ual-scatter)
- [Lynx UAL](https://github.com/EOSIO/ual-lynx)
- [Ledger UAL](https://github.com/EOSIO/ual-ledger)
- [Token-Pocket UAL](https://github.com/EOSIO/ual-token-pocket)
- [Meet.One UAL](https://github.com/meet-one/ual-meetone)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by dapp browsers but if you want web browsers to interact with EOS blockchain, you can look at [eosjs](https://github.com/eosio/eosjs).